# How do I rear my horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I'm scaling steep corners of mountains with my horse, it becomes sometimes inevitable to take a fatal leap, even when I steer backwards using the "back" key.

Is there a way to rear my horse, so I can "undo" the distance from the point of no return back to safety?

I am playing on the PC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When pressing the jump button while standing (i.e. without moving), the horse will "rear up", and back off a bit. If you do it a couple of times, you will have enough room to make your turn safely.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that..

Comment: No problem, before finding it I also had a lot of moments of standing on the edge of a cliff and realizing: "Oh, well... I'm dead. Sucks. :/".  I understand your pain.

Comment: Yes, the spacebar on the PC. Edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Well, horses have the same behavior on pc and consoles, so... should work the same on both? How is your horse dying if you are standing still?